# using Firebase Crashlytics in Xamarin iOS

Tags: firebase, xamarin.ios, crashlytics

Could anyone please help me in how to use Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics nuget package for Xamarin iOS. I am getting SIGSEGV code error in my code at random places and I am not able to figure out the actual problem. 
Have searched a lot regarding how to implement Crashlytics in Xamarin iOS , but I was not able to find any.
Have followed the steps given in the below two links, but I was only able to implement Crashlytics in xcode with the help of these two links.
[Link 1](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68256/fabric-crashlytics-answers-and-digits-for-xamarin-forms-xamarin-android-and-xamarin-ios) [Link 2](https://www.fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install)

Comment: Hi, Paul from Crashlytics here. FYI, we don't officially support Xamarin at this time.

Comment: Hi, Paul. If there is no support for Crashlytics in Xamarin. Then what does Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics nuget package does?? I can see two packages in Xamarin Nuget Manager, one for Firebase Crash Reporting and one for Crashlytics?

Comment: @buser well, Xamarin team [does it](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/03c7782cbc16d874e57ba01db31a6be8e6b8aa12/Firebase.Crashlytics/component/GettingStarted.md)

Comment: @MikalaiDaronin could you please tell me the steps? I am not able to implement it in Xamarin iOS project

Comment: @AnshumanSingh the [readme file](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/03c7782cbc16d874e57ba01db31a6be8e6b8aa12/Firebase.Crashlytics/component/GettingStarted.md) should help. There is nothing expect adding the [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics/), `GoogleService-Info.plist` and a few lines of code.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. What i am not able to do is to upload a dysm file.In fabric it is showing as "It looks like we are missing dSYMs to process crashes for the versions below." a particular uuid file is missing which i am not able to upload?

Comment: Any news about this? Were you able to make Firebase Crashlytics works in Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez , Yes I have implemented this in both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Forms, find my findings in below answer

Comment: @MikalaiDaronin I've finished the ReadMe's steps, and I couldn't make it work. Can you help me out pls?

Comment: @anitteb I only followed steps from that readme file and that's all. You probably need to open an issue on Github if you have some troubles with the package

Comment: @MikalaiDaronin what solved my issue was this answer below. I think the key was the run script, which cannot be added in Visual Studio. At least I couldn't find a way. I've deleted the app from Fabric Dashboard and my test crashes still appear on Firebase Dashboard. So is working now.

Comment: @AnshumanSingh I have added an answer in detail you may take a look

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you solved the problem already or not but I will give it a go since this post almost got me to the finish line. And there might be others out there looking for how to do this.

As of late 2018 the Crashlytics is going from Fabric to Firebase this has resulted in a lot of old posts that are not applicable any more.

To get nuGet package to work you will need to do the following:

Head over to the [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and create a project. Then add an app input a "bundle ID", this needs to be the same as what you have in your xamarin app. The nick and App Store ID is optional.

You will now get a GoogleService-Info.plist file, download this file. Now comes the the tricky part. To initialize the firebase app you need to create a dummy xCode project with the same bundle identifier as your project to do this:

Make a new xCode project and follow the instructions from [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started)

Remember to use the .xcworkspace file to open the project after insatlling the pods.

Compile and run this app on a device in the firebase console you will hopefully see some reaction if everything has worked out correctly.

Now to add this to your visualStudio xamarin app first include the GoogleService-Info.plist to your project and change the build action to "Bundle Resource"
Then add the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core and Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics packages to the iOS project.

Almost there, only two things left to do.

In the AppDelegate.cs file in the FinishedLaunching function add:

```
Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
Crashlytics.Configure();
Fabric.Fabric.SharedSdk.Debug = true; // To enable debugging
```

and also remember to add the two namespaces Firebase.Core and Firebase.Crashlytics to the top of the file.

The last step is to run the app witout the debugger as the debugger will eat all the errors.

This should be it.

More info on the crashlytics nuGet see the [github page](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/Crashlytics/GettingStarted.md)

**Edit**

**2019-08-03:** updated link to getting started NuGet

Comment: The GitHub link does not work you might wanna update that!!

Comment: Should be updated now upstream repo had some restructuring done without leaving a trace.,, making dead links :(

Answer (score 1):

**PLEASE CHECK THE COMMENTS**

For iOS:

- Add GoogleService-Info.plist file to your app project.
- Set GoogleService-Info.plist build action behaviour to Bundle Resource by Right-clicking/Build Action.
- Add the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core NuGet to your iOS project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics/
- Add the following lines of code somewhere in your app, typically in your AppDelegate’s FinishedLaunching method (don't forget to import Firebase.Core and Firebase.Crashlytics namespace):

  ```
     App.Configure ();
     Crashlytics.Configure ();
  ```

For Android:

- Make sure you have a project set up in the Firebase Developer Console.
- Download your project’s file and place it in the folder of your Xamarin.Android project.
- Add the Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics/
- Restart your IDE
- Add google-services.json to your Xamarin.Android app project.
- Set the build action google-services.json to GoogleServicesJson
- Create a string resource with the name com.crashlytics.android.build_id. The value can be whatever you want to uniquely identify a particular build with.
  Clean and Rebuild your solution.

  ```
    Fabric.Fabric.With(this, new Crashlytics.Crashlytics());
    Crashlytics.Crashlytics.HandleManagedExceptions();
  ```

I had recently written a blog for integrating your Xamarin Apps with Firebase Crashlytics where I have gone in detail on how it can be configured which can be found here:

https://medium.com/@hakimgulamali88/firebase-crashlytics-with-xamarin-5421089bb561

Comment: This comment is obsolete. In 2021, the nuget you need to add is called `Xamarin.iOS.Firebase.Crashlytics`, it has a dependency on abovementioned `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core` nuget (so no need to add individually) and also `Crashlytics.Configure();` method is no longer there and isn't called.

Comment: The linked article is also obsolete, as there's no Fabric namespace anymore and the test method to cause a crash is also not present. The code samples are unusable.

Comment: @masiton Thanks for the update will look into it and update the answer and my blog.

Comment: thanks. If you feel like it, please take a look at my issue, I'm really struggling to get the crashlytics to work in Xamarin.Forms (iOS) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804943/firebase-crashlytics-not-showing-up-for-xamarin-forms-app-ios-despite-build-s

Answer (score -2):

There are few steps needed to be performed in order to implement Firebase Crashlytics in Xamarin.

First of all you have to create a dummy project in Xcode with same bundle identifier.

You can follow this https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install , to implement Crashlytics in Xcode.

Now for Xamarin, use the same Bundle Identifier, and in the info.plist file add the below lines

```
<key>Fabric</key>
<dict>
<key>APIKey</key>
<string>Your api key</string>
<key>Kits</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>KitInfo</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>KitName</key>
    <string>Crashlytics</string>
  </dict>
</array>
</dict>
```

Now import Fabric and Crashlytics in the AppDelegate , then initialize Fabric instance with:

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

Comment: Unable to use the above code to initialise Crashlytics. If anyone has solved it, Please share the steps.

Comment: As the questioner, I would like to view my crashes on Firebase Crashlytics, not on Fabric dashboard (which will be not supported soon)