# Problems setting up Firebase Crashlytics in Xamarin iOS and Android projects

Tags: android, ios, firebase, xamarin, crashlytics

First of all, I know this question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705163/using-firebase-crashlytics-in-xamarin-ios#). Unfortunately, it is not working for me, applies only to iOS, there are few instructions available online, and the Nuget packages are updated fairly often. There doesn't even seem to be any "official" documentation for this. However, I did find [this article](https://medium.com/@hakimgulamali88/firebase-crashlytics-with-xamarin-5421089bb561) and followed it 100% multiple times, even deleting and recreating firebase projects in the hopes that something had gone wrong with no luck. The article was written before the latest versions of the Nuget packages, so perhaps something has changed. This is what I have done:

iOS:

1. Created my firebase project specifying the bundle id to match the Bundle Identifier in the Info.plist file.
2. Downloaded GoogleService-Info.plist, added it to my Xamarin iOS project and set the build action to BundleResource
3. Added Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics via Nuget (v. 3.14.0.3)
4. added the following lines of code to the FinishedLaunching method of the AppDelegate class

```
Fabric.Fabric.SharedSdk.Debug = true;
Firebase.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Configure();
Firebase.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.SharedInstance.Crash();
```

When I run the app (both debug and release modes), the crash happens, but no events are pushed to Firebase and there are no related messages in the Application Output window to suggest what may have gone wrong.

Some sources say I need to add the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core nuget package, which I have tried (v. 6.6.6) along with App.Configure() in the same method above. Unfortunately when I do this, I cannot build the project. I get a vast number of "Native linking failed, undefined symbol..." build errors.

What I am missing?

Android:

1. Created my firebase project specifying the bundle id to match the Package Name in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. Downloaded google-services.json, added it to my Xamarin Android project and set the build action to GoogleServicesJson
3. Added Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics via Nuget (v. 2.9.4.4)
4. Added a strings.xml file to the Resources/values folder with a build action of AndroidResource and added this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">236</string>
</resources>
```

5. Added the following lines of code to the OnCreate method of the MainActivity class

```
Fabric.Fabric.With(this, new Crashlytics.Crashlytics());
Crashlytics.Crashlytics.HandleManagedExceptions();
Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Instance.Crash();
```

When I run the app (both in release and debug modes), the crash happens, but no events are pushed to Firebase. In debug mode, the following entries exist in the Application Output window:

[Fabric] Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/[bundle-id]/settings

[Answers] Failed to retrieve settings

[CrashlyticsCore] Received null settings, skipping report submission!

And after the crash is logged to the console:

[CrashlyticsCore] Cannot send reports. Settings are unavailable.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

****** UPDATE ******

Following the suggestion of @Leon MSFT below, I installed ALL dependencies for the Android project individually by looking at the nuget dependency list for each. Now I can successfully initialize Crashlytics, it successfully detects the error and tries to report it but I get:

```
[CrashlyticsCore] java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
[CrashlyticsCore]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
[CrashlyticsCore]   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
[CrashlyticsCore]   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:320)
[CrashlyticsCore]   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:300)
[CrashlyticsCore]   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:42)
```

For iOS, I tried installing all Xamarin.Firebase.iOS nuget packages and dependencies, but still cannot build- various Native linked failed, undefined symbol build errors.

Comment: In the android, dependencies are nor recognized correctly, so you should install directly these nugets as well:https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/93#issuecomment-460583641

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT This has gotten me closer. See Update above